# Share a URL that contains a Player with 3 types of video

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, share, jwplayer

This is the thing:

I have a codeigniter's application and it has a view to play a specific video.
I'm using 3 types of formats for that: FLV, MP4 and WEBM, in order to cover all cases of Browsers for HTML5 and Flash.

HTML5 for Mozilla (WEBM), Chrome (MP4), Safari (MP4) and IE9 (MP4).
IE7 and IE8 Flash (FLV).

Then, for JW Player I use block LEVELS and MODES to switch HTML5 FLASH or viceversa, depending browser.

The point I want to emphasize is this: The view has three different meta tags for facebook:

```
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/webm" />
```

When sharing my video into facebook using PHP-SDK I have a problem only in Mozilla because I can't play it on the user's wall. And I don't know if its necessary specify the 3 types of video on the player or should I put only one type and facebook does its magic and plays in all browsers?

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this so we can debug the issue?